# how to select @domain from email and match from another table with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

i have two tables first is users table

```
+------------------------------------
|  Useid    |  user email    | name  |
|-----------|----------------|-----  |
|  1        | sara@yahoo.com |sara   |
+------------------------------------
```

second is foundation table

```
+-------------------------------
|fo_name           |  fo_email  |  
|----------------  |------------|
|Florida universty | @yahoo.com | 
---------------------------------
```

note : first i will search by userid..it not work..can anyone help..

```
select fo_name,fo_email
(select 
  d_users.user_id,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(d_users.user_email,@) // some regex or substr code to cut domain
FROM d_users
where d_users.user_id = '1'
) as substr_email
from foundation
where fo_email = substr_email;
```

i want to select the foundation that match user_email how to do that

by `regex` or by `substr_index` or anything

user email like that sara@yahoo.com or adam@hotmail.com

foundation email like that  **@yahoo.com** or like that **@hotmail.com**

Comment: the example you gave is quite unclear do you mean "like '%@yahoo.com'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want:

```
select 
    f.fo_name, f.fo_email, d.user_id, d.substr_email
from
    foundation f
        inner join
    (select 
        d_users.user_id,
        RIGHT(user_email, (LENGTH(user_email) - LOCATE('@', user_email) + 1)) as substr_email
    FROM
        d_users
    where
        d_users.user_id = '1') d ON f.fo_email = d.substr_email;
```

though this is a very strange (bad) way of joining tables, with calculating foreign key each time.

**UPDATE:**

OK, I have updated my answer and made example at SQLFiddle, so please check it out - [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5edaf/4)

Comment: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Yes, subquery cannot return more than 1 column... I have removed it now, so this should work.

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'substr_email' in 'where clause'

Comment: OK, I have updated my answer and made example at SQLFiddle, so please check it out - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5edaf/4

Answer (score 0):

First of all:
If you have a foundation table, your user table should have a foreign key to point this table.

For example, your user table can become:

```
id
username
fk_foundation
name
```

So your example data becomes:

```
id = 1
username = sara
fk_foundation = id (of foundation table, in your example is not specified)
name = sara
```

Your query with current table structure can be (but performance can be nasty):

```
select *
from user u
join foundation f
on u.email like '%' + f.fo_email
where f.fo_email = '@yahoo.com'
```

If you change your table structure the query will become:

```
select *
from user u
join foundation f
on u.fk_foundation = f.id
where f.fo_email = '@yahoo.com'
```

More faster than the first

Comment: @user1080247: Yes, but can you add it?

Comment: @user1080247: Ok, so you can use the first query (with like)